# How primary key in one table connect to other table with the same primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How primary key in one table connect to another table with the same primary key?

I am trying to make it like this, which those two primary key in the table of CustomerCreditCard is connect to the table of Customer and table of Credit card]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIBUE.png

```
--3
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    CustomerID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);

--5
CREATE TABLE CreditCard
(
    CreditCardNumber    VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    CreditCardOwnerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);

--6
CREATE TABLE CustomerCreditCard
(
    CreditCardNumber VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID       INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(CreditCardNumber, CustomerID)
);
```

Comment: Its usually better to always have a non-meaningful PK i.e. your CreditCard should really also had its own identity column. That said, what issues are you having with that you are doing?

Comment: Currently, the table of CustomerCreditCard is not connecting to other tables, I want to make it like the picture I provided.

Comment: What happens when you run you script above?

Comment: `the table of CustomerCreditCard is not connecting to other tables` :- [Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: When i run the script, the primary key of customerCreditCard is not connect to the table of credit card, and table of customer, since customerCreditCard have two primary key and I want those two primary key connect to other table which have the same primary key that the table of customerCredit card has.

Comment: If this question is how do I create a foreign key using the tool in the link you need to tell us the tool. BTW connected is the wrong term and you only need FKs for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--6
CREATE TABLE CustomerCreditCard
(
CreditCardNumber            VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
CustomerID                  INT NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_CustomerCreditCard
PRIMARY KEY(CreditCardNumber,CustomerID ),

CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerCreditCard_CreditCardNumber
FOREIGN KEY(CreditCardNumber)
REFERENCES CreditCard(CreditCardNumber)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerCreditCard_CustomerID
FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID)
REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

);
```

To solve the problem of this question, add the foreign key to the table that has two primary keys, then reference to other tables that you want to connect with the same primary key.

Comment: Is that the answer? Or clarification to the question?

Comment: This is the answer that fixed my problem.